# Azure Devops: How to order query by custom backlog order?

Tags: azure-devops

In Azure DevOps you can custom order items in a field called *Order*.
How do you order a Query by this order?  What is the *Order* field name?

[image]  [image]

Answer (score 0):

Order in this context is just a line count.

You can drag items to different lines and the 'Order' will stay the same.